# iOS Swift - Best approach for UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, datasource

I need to know what is the best approach to handle iOS UITableView and UITableViewCell. I need to know if it is good enought that the table datasource to be stored in the same class (the viewcontroller class) as the tableview. Ex.: on the top of the view class, store objects in Data, where Cells is a struct defined there.

One more question: How to handle like button on UITableViewCell?

Every cell from the table is an object type Struct from Data. For every cell, I've got a number ( likes number ) and a variable alreadyLiked. I've added a button to cell, and set that button to selected or unselected (in function of alreadyLiked variable). Than I've added a target to every button, with a selector. Is that a good approach?

Answer (score 2):

For iOS we use the Model - View - Controller paradigma. 
Models = data
View = what the user sees
Controller = the glue between those 2

So it's not really a good idea to store your data in the Controller. Create a model and use that model in your ViewController to show the data. This way you can change your model implementation easily without having to worry about your views or vice versa. Eg you could store your data in your model via CoreData, via SQLite or get it from a website without the View or Controller knowing where it comes from or how it's stored.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'll create a separate class to manage the model and in the TableViewController I'll create an array with objects of the model type and a function to download data (json download and parse) for that class. Is it ok?

Comment: Depending on your needs and data this can be a good approach. It's good if you don't have a huge volume of data (the array is kept in memory). Otherwise it would be better to let you model handle that as well and you provide a method: giveMeElementAt (index:integer). In you model you could then load the data from CoreData or a SQLite database